# Spring WebClient ClientResponse times out on bodyToMono

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

This is the API call (blocking) I am making to external application concurrently (max of 100 calls at the same time)

```
ClientResponse response = webclient.get()
    .uri("https-url-here-with-query-params-here")
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "abcdefg")
    .exchange()
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
    .block();

if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
    MyPojoEntity myPojo = response.bodyToMono(MyPojoEntity.class)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
        .block();
}
```

What I observe is the call to `response.bodyToMono(MyPojoEntity.class).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))` is timing out after 5 minutes. My understanding is ClientResponse already has response body from the server and `response.bodyToMono` method just unmarshalling to pojo entity class. The payload is very small and shouldn't take more than few seconds to unmarshall it. May be it is still reading the response from server and timing out due to API issue on the server? If that is the case, then what does `if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful())` mean? I expect when response status is success, payload also to be there especially when i retrieve ClientResponse in a blocking way.  Please help me to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Why are you blocking _twice_? Why not use `bodyToMono` on the exchange _then_ block? `ClientResponse` does not already have the body!

Comment: Hi Boris, We have specific error handling and retries based on http status code. Otherwise, i could have used retrieve() instead of exchange() and parsed the response body in one blocking call itself.

Comment: That can all be done within the reactive pipeline.

Comment: Sure retries can be done in the same pipeline but let us not digress here and i just want to understand what is happening in the implementation i have here. It is not that it is timing out all the time..it works almost all the time and i can understand if it times out on the first blocking call but i can't explain the timeout on the response extraction unless it is still communicating to the server

Comment: It is still communicating with the server.

Comment: Target API service is not reactive. It is spring web based not webflux based and it returns response body along with status 200 at the same time.

Comment: I’m not sure how that’s relevant. Like most HTTP clients, web client reads the headers then leaves the socket open to stream the content. No HTTP client that’s well written reads the body into memory without being told to do so.

Comment: It's probably because you are blocking twice.

Comment: I don't think blocking twice is causing the issue. If that is the case, i expect this to fail every time. @Boris, true but RestTemplate with 300 secs read timeout never fails.

Comment: Then use a rest template - if you’re blocking anyway